# Невидимые области на экране, для управления игрой

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Как сделать для андроида невидимую область на экране(правая половина экрана- левая половина экрана), тапая на которую можно вызвать необходимый скрипт.( т.е. для управления GO).
Вот этот скрипт не работает.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class controler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private Touch touch;
    void Update()
    {
        int fingerCount = 0;
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
                fingerCount++;

        }


        if (fingerCount > 0)

        {
            if (touch.position.x < (Screen.width / 2))
                player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y - 90f, 0);

        }
        else player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + 90f, 0);

    }
}
```

Почему,что не правильно?
Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный ниже скрипт поворачивает объект направо - налево, в зависимости от стороны экрана, которой коснулись.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class turner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private bool rot = false;
    void Update()
    {
        {
            if (Input.touchCount == 0) rot = false;
            if (rot) return;
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
                if (Input.touches[0].phase != TouchPhase.Ended && Input.touches[0].phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
                {
                    rot = true;
                    if (Input.touches[0].position.x > (Screen.width / 2))
                    {
                        player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, +90f, Space.Self);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -90f, Space.Self);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему вы хотите реализовать управление персонажем. В целом наверное должен работать скрипт, вот только ваша переменная `touch` для класса `controler` нигде не инициализируется. У вас в `Update` в цикле используется переменная с тем же именем, но она перестает существовать после того как программа выходит из цикла. Если вас интересует только первый тач, то можно в цикле задавать `this.touch = touch; break;` и дальше уже его обрабатывать, но мне кажется это неправильно, надо каждое касание обрабатывать.

Comment: вы правы. Это управление персонажем. Персонаж стоит перед выбором(право - лево), и выбор за игроком, касание слава или справа. На следующем препятствии все повторяется. То есть в момент выбора интересует первое касание. А в течении игры все последующие. Посмотрите, я правильно воспользовался вашим советом? Не помогло.      if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
                fingerCount++;
            this.touch = touch;
            break;

Comment: А как вы собираетесь обрабатывать когда нажмут сразу двумя пальцами? рано или поздно такое ситуэйшен точно произойдет.
Возьмите в скобки чтобы обрабатывались все команды пакетом, а не только первый счетчик увеличивался.

`if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled) {fingerCount++; this.touch = touch; break;}`

Comment: я не понимаю в чем дело. У меня юнити не реагирует на touch. Или и не должна? Клик мышью в редакторе равнозначен касанию на экране? Я не компилировал, проверял в редакторе мышкой.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Прошу прощения за тупость и занудство. Я пытался управлять в редакторе мышью.)) На самом деле скрипт работает, но надо допилить. Повороты вправо - влево возможны только по очереди, а может понадобиться несколько поворотов в одну сторону подряд.Либо это глобальные координаты.